# Issue with img-fluid of bootstrap 4 in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

There is issue with img-fluid of bootstrap 4 in IE.
I am displaying the image in model dialog of bootstrap 4.The image's has actual size **2000*400**.

But I am displaying the image in modal popup of bootstrap 4 and image has class **"img-fluid"** so it is resized into size **734*148** and extra space at the end of the modal popup appears.

If I added image having smaller size than 734*148 then extra space does not appears, that means there is issue with large size images.

If I remove img-fluid class of large size image, then extra space does not appear but image displayed out of the modal-dialog, that I don't want.

**The extra space only appears in Internet Explorer and not in firefox and chrome.**

I tried to solve the issue by adding **d-block, w-100, h-100** classes to parent element of image, but it does not work.

So is there any solution for this?

**Extra space screen shot:**
[image]

**Popup without Image:**
[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample sreenshot demonstrating the issue

Comment: I have updated the question with screen shot @Mat J

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modal, add *overflow: hidden* to the style of the modal body.

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: hidden">
```

And be sure to use the modal-header and footer. Off course, add this to a class in your css, scss or other style files you are creating ;)

Be aware that this will not show the scrollbars anymore! But if you only need to show the image, this should do the trick.